# Make resizable plots using the grid graphing system in R

Tags: r, graphics, customization, r-grid

Recently I read about the grid graphing system in R.  It is very flexible and with its mastery one should be able to make very sophisticated graphs.  However I have not found any good place that will allow me to plot a graph that is also re-sizable?  The question is as follows: How do you use `grid` graphing system in `R` so that the final output is actually resizable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing so is not using the grip graphing system directly, but use the `lattice` interface to it. The `lattice` package comes installed with R as far as I know, and forms a very flexible interface to the underlying `Trellis` graphs, which are grid-based graphs. `Lattice` also allows you to manipulate the grid directly, so in fact for most sophisticated graphs that will be all you need.

If you really are going to work with the grid graphing system itself, you have to use the correct coordinate system for it to be scalable. Either "native", "npc" (Normalized Parent Coordinates) or "snpc" (Square Normalized Parent Coordinates) allow you to rescale a figure, as they give the coordinates relative to the size (or one aspect of it) of the current viewport.

In order to make full use of these, make sure you understand the concept of viewports very well. I have to admit that I still have a lot to learn about it. If you really want to get on with it, I can suggest the book [R Graphics from Paul Murrell](http://www.crcpress.com/ecommerce_product/product_detail.jsf?catno=C486X&isbn=0000000000000&parent_id=&pc=)

Take a closer look at chapter 5 of that book. You can also learn a lot from the R code of the examples, which can also be found on [this page](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/rgraphics.html)

To give you one :

```
grid.circle(x=seq(0.1, 0.9, length=100), 
            y=0.5 + 0.4*sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length=100)),
            r=abs(0.1*cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length=100))))
```

Perfectly scaleable. If you look at the help pages of `grid.circle`, you'll find the `default.units="npc"` option. That's where in this case the correct coordinate system is set. Compare to

```
grid.circle(x=seq(0.1, 0.9, length=100), 
            y=0.5 + 0.4*sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length=100)),
            r=abs(0.1*cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length=100))),
            default.units="inch")
```

which is not scaleable.

Comment: does this mean that if i have to have the "resizing" ability with grid graphics in R, I have to start plotting the entire graph with the same graphing system? I have the book that you suggested.  I will read the relevant portion again and see if it now makes more sense.

Comment: @Sam : It's especially important to take care you use the correct coordinate system. If you specify locations in inches, the plot is not scalable. If you specify them in npc or in native (which is relative to the axes), they are scaleable. But there are so many aspects to it that it's impossible to summarize it all here if there's no specific example. If you follow the examples in the book, you'll get somewhere.